# How do I preview a report by adding an existing datasource in ssrs in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, datasource, rds

I just started a new job, and I'm coming from a primary focus on SSIS. As such my SSRS skills are a touch rough. The research I've done so far suggests what I'm trying to do may not be possible, but I'm hopeful that the transition from BIDS to VS 2010 may include this feature.

I am responsible for all existing reports for my division. TFS has only the .rdl files, and the data source appears to be a shortcut. When I go into the shortcut to look up the properties I get something like the following:

```
/DivisionInitials/Data Sources/DatasourceName
```

I have tried to add a new data source, but currently I'm having issues linking it. I'm also concerned because I'm not sure if that is going to break the report once I redeploy it.

Any advice? Any research items to point to?

Comment: When you are deploying a SSRS project you can set if you want to overwrite datasources and datasets. Check your project configuration in deployement settings.

Comment: I'm not trying to deploy. I'm going for a first look only.

Comment: I just added a new shared data source, and I found where to link the .rdl file to the new source. I'm still not 100% sure that I have the data source defined the same way it was originally set up. It is a work around until I can find a better answer.

Comment: From the location, the data sources should be located in a **/DivisionInitials/Data Sources/** subfolder of your solution in TFS. We usually leave them in the same folder and deploy to a separate **Data Source** folder.

Comment: They didn't do that. The only thing they put into TFS was the .rdl files. I want to eventually push to have the entire project stored in TFS, but that is a fight for another day.